# E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when install (sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop) give that error :sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151901/e:-could-not-get-lock-/var/lib/dpkg/lock---open-(11:-resource-temporarily-unavailable)/) by [AbdallahHesham](https://answers.ros.org/users/14711/abdallahhesham/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This indicates some other process is currently (potentially) modifying your packages. You first have to end that process so your "apt-get" process is allowed to take the lock and install packages. A typical example of this happens if you have "sudo synaptic" or the package updater running and try to install packages using "apt-get" at the same time.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3